# valid geojson file and no polygons - gMaps 3

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I am unable to display json data (geojson) on a google map. I have checked my json file at jslint and it does not report any such errors.

I am getting the following error message: InvalidValueError: in property "features": at index 0: in property "geometry": in property "coordinates": at index 0: at index 5: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number.

Sample code below:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(53.760861, -98.813876),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 5
});

// Load a GeoJSON from the same server as our demo.
map.data.loadGeoJson('data.json');

} // end initialize

 google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initialize );
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does your GeoJSON look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  There is a working example in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

You should check your GeoJSON using http://www.geojsonlint.com Your JSON can be perfectly valid but that doesn't mean it's valid GeoJSON. For instance the error your getting:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": ["Foo", "Bar"]
    }
}
```

The above is valid JSON, although it's not valid GeoJSON, the coordinate array should contain numbers, not strings. Even if you had `coordinates: ["1", "2"]`, it would still be invalid, because those are strings which is not the same as `coordinates: [1, 2]` which are real numbers.

Check your GeoJSON using the link i shared above and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, this was helpful. As it turns out the geojson file is not json serializable. I will need to revist the geojson file and determine what is wrong with it.

Cheers